# How to debug applescript when an Application's class methods don't respond

Tags: applescript, textedit, macvim

In Applescript, I'm trying to change which text editor I'm using.  TextEdit works fine, providing the document name, and it opens in MacVim.  However, when I try the exact same `get path of document 1` command in MacVim, it stays undefined, and terminal shows error:

> execution error: MacVim got an error: Can’t get document 1. Invalid index. (-1719)

The MacVim library claims it uses the same document object, both really coming from the 'Standard Suite'.

What's my next debug step?

**All the Details Below Here**

Applescript code to "toggle text editing apps" of the currently open and focused file:

```
on run argv
    set my_arg to argv
    set the_path to "error - not found"
    
    if (my_arg contains "v") then
        set the_path to from_app("TextEdit")
        open_in_app("MacVim", the_path)
    else if (my_arg contains "e") then
        set the_path to from_app("MacVim")
        open_in_app("TextEdit", the_path)
    else
        display dialog "Error: Use argument 'e' or 'v' to switch TO textEditor or macVim"
    end if
end run

on from_app(from_app)
    tell application from_app
        activate
        set my_path to get path of document 1
        close document 1
    end tell
    
    return my_path
end from_app

on open_in_app(to_app, my_path)
    tell application to_app
        activate
        open my_path
    end tell
end open_in_app
```

Standard Suite in TextEdit

> document n [inh. item; see also TextEdit suite] : A document.
> elements: contained by application, application. properties: path
> (text) : The document's path.

TextEdit suite in TextEdit

> document n [see also Standard Suite] : A TextEdit document.
> properties: text (text) : The text of the document.

Standard Suite in MacVim

> document n [inh. item] : A document. elements: contained by
> application. properties: path (text) : The document's path.

Not seeing how to make these images smaller yet...

[image]
[image]
[image]

**How I call the script to get the error**

```
user@userMBP % osascript ~/toggle-text-editor.apple.scpt e
```

**Versions**

MacVim was installed with `brew install macvim`, `Custom Version 9.0.65 (173)`.

Mac is Bug Sur version `11.6.8 (20G730)`

**Answers to questions**

> Does homebrew install a gui "MacVim"? Is it launched when the script runs?

Yes, MacVim includes a GUI, and it is successfully launched when the script runs.

> What returns from path to application "MacVim"? Is it correct?

Not sure what you mean.  `open my_path` successfully opens the right document in MacVim.  `set my_path to get path of document 1` fails.

> What returns from tell application "Macvim" to documents?

Again, not sure what you mean.  There are 2 lines that can issue a `tell application MacVim`.  One is successful (opening document), one fails (asking MacVim the name of currently open document).

Thank you @Mockman and @CJK. Opened [issue1226](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/1266) on MacVim github.

Comment: That error typically implies that there isn't a document 1 available, at least from the script's perspective (including at the time it runs). Does homebrew install a gui "MacVim" as well as cli? Is it launched when the script runs? What returns from `path to application "MacVim"`? Is it correct? What returns from `tell application "Macvim" to documents`?

Comment: @Mockman, I updated post with answers, but I'm not sure what you mean by 2 of them.  `tell` seems to be affecting MacVim correctly, and MacVim is receiving and executing the request to open a document correctly.  The call that fails is it does not seem to understand `document 1`.  Do you see any more debug info I can collect?

Comment: You’re not doing anything wrong.  MacVim’s scripting hasn’t been implemented properly, so you won’t be able to get it to work.

Comment: @Polo Well, there you have it. Perhaps you could look into emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step was to go to the developer of the Application.  In this case, I opened [issue1226](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/1266) on MacVim github.